# 外部クラスを使用しようとしたが、コンパイル時にパッケージが見つからないと表示される

Tags: java

自分java初心者で、外部クラスを使用したわけなのですが、コンパイル時にimportしているパッケージは見つからないと表示されました。何がいけないのでしょうか。

App.java

```
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.poi.EncryptedDocumentException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class App {
    File file;
    Workbook excel;
    Sheet sheet;
    Row row;
    Cell cell;

    App(String path) {
        file = new File(path);
        try{
            excel = WorkbookFactory.create(file);
        }catch(IOException ie) {
            System.out.println("error");
        }
        sheet = excel.getSheet("user_data");

        row = sheet.getRow(2);

        cell = row.getCell(0);
        System.out.println(cell.getStringCellValue());
    }
}
```

Frame.java

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SpringLayout;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.io.File;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.SpringLayout;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

class Frame extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    JFrame frame;
    JButton button;
    JLabel label;
    JTextField textField;
    SpringLayout s;
    JPanel panel;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Frame();
    }

    Frame() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(400, 200);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        panel = new JPanel();
        s = new SpringLayout();
        panel.setLayout(s);

        textField = new JTextField(20);
        textField.addActionListener(this);
        textField.setText("bin\\Excel.xlsx");

        label = new JLabel("Enter the Path");

        button = new JButton("Enter");
        button.addActionListener(this);

        s.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, textField, 10, SpringLayout.SOUTH, frame);
        s.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, textField, 30, SpringLayout.WEST, frame);

        s.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, label, -10, SpringLayout.NORTH, textField);
        s.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, label, 10, SpringLayout.WEST, textField);

        s.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, button, 0, SpringLayout.SOUTH, textField);
        s.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, button, 20, SpringLayout.EAST, textField);

        panel.add(textField);
        panel.add(label);
        panel.add(button);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(new File(textField.getText()).exists()) {
            new App(textField.getText());
            frame.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(this, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
        }else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "This file doesn't exist.", "Invalid File", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: 階層構造]

[image: 実行結果]

Comment: コンパイル時のコマンドについて、クラスパスが`poi-4.1.2`になっている箇所を`poi-bin-5.2.2`に書き換えるとエラーは解消するでしょうか？

Comment: 気づいてませんでした、、、変えてみたのですが、同じ結果になったので別の原因かもしれません。画像は更新しました。

Comment: 次は`poi-bin-5.2.2`をすべて`./poi-bin-5.2.2`に置換して動くか試してみてください。

Comment: :とすべきところを；にしていませんか？

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。最初の";"を":"に直し、`./poi-bin-5.2.2`としたのですが、[同じ結果でした](https://i.imgur.com/oqHojLk.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [javacコマンド > ユーザー・クラス・パスの指定例](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/17/docs/specs/man/javac.html#example-of-specifying-a-user-class-path)

にある通り、クラスパスのセパレータはOSによって異なり、 Windowsではセミコロン `;` です。

従って、コンパイルするためのコマンドは次のようになります:

```
javac -classpath .;poi-bin-5.2.2/*;poi-bin-5.2.2/lib/*;poi-bin-5.2.2/ooxml-lib/* src\*.java
```

こういった質問は画像で提出されると状況を再現しづらいので、テキストで行ってください。